# Can I keep SQL Server 2005 mdf file of version 612 in SQL Server 2008 express edition of version 655

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have SQL Server 2005 `.mdf` file of version 612 and it should be opened in SQL Server 2008 Express of version 655. Is it possible to run lower version(612) `.mdf` file in Higher version(655) express ??

Comment: IMHO restore/attache a .mdf from a lower version to higher version sql server should have no problem due to backward compatibility. I have tried to restore/attach .mdf from 2008 to 2012 and 2014 before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you attach the `.mdf` from SQL Server 2005 with version 612 to SQL Server 2008, it will be **upgraded** to the internal file version 655.

So yes - you can go from 2005 to 2008 - **once** - but you can **never** go back. Once the file is upgraded, it cannot ever be attached in SQL Server **2005** anymore

Comment: Thanks for your reply.can i move .mdf from SQL Server 2005 express edition with version 612 to SQL Server 2008 r2 express with version 661 and also to SQL Server 2012 express with version 705 ?? @marc_s

Comment: @user2801432: yes - you can always go "upwards" - from 2005 to 2008 R2 and to 2012 - but you can **never** go back down...